# Linq-select group from specific date

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

**Problem:** Looking to select 1 row of each type

**Table:** EntryPrices

AttendingTypesId (int)

Name (nvarchar)

Price (int)

GroupId (int)

FromDate (DateTime) //yyyy-MM-dd

**Sample:**
Basic entry - 100 - 1 - 2012-08-01

Sponsor entry - 350 - 2 - 2012-08-01

Staff entry - 70 - 3 - 2012-08-01

Basic entry - 150 - 1 - 2012-10-01

Basic entry - 200 - 1 - 2012-12-01

As you can see, there are 3 basic entries. Each is valid depending on the date when they registered.
So if a person registers in mid september, he gets it for 100
mid November 150 and end December 200.

However i want to get the "valid" fee depending on todays date and i want to list that in a dropdown list.

> So if i query this today (2012-aug-02) i should get the following
>   rows:
>
> Basic entry - 100 - 1 - 2012-08-01
>
> Sponsor entry - 350 - 2 - 2012-08-01
>
> Staff entry - 70 - 3 - 2012-08-01
>
> If i query this (2012-dec-20) i should get the following rows:
>
> Sponsor entry - 350 - 2 - 2012-08-01
>
> Staff entry - 70 - 3 - 2012-08-01
>
> Basic entry - 200 - 1 - 2012-12-01

How can i construct this in linq-to-sql?

My idea was something like:

```
var f = from data in mc.AttendingTypes
                    where DateTime.Now.CompareTo(data.FromDate) > 0
                    group data by new { data.GroupId, data.Name, data.Price, data.AttendingTypesId }
                    into newData
                    select new { newData.Key.Name, newData.Key.Price, newData.Key.AttendingTypesId };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd rather do something like that :

```
var today = DateTime.Now;

var result = mc.AttendingTypes
             .Where(at => at.FromDate <= today)
             .GroupBy(at => at.GroupId)
             .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(m => m.FromDate).FirstOrDefault())
             .ToList();
```

Comment: .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(m => m.FromDate).First()) to .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(m => m.FromDate).FirstOrDefault()) and it worked perfectly.